# How can I configure multiple ports for a multiapp Ionic 6/VueJs 3 project in a config file?

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3, ionic6

I have an Ionic 6/VueJs 3 multi app project and I would like to be able to open each project in a different, permanent port during development...

Here is a config...

```
{
  "defaultProject": "app1",
  "projects": {
    "app1": {
      "name": "app1",
      "integrations": {
        "capacitor": {}
      },
      "type": "vue",
      "root": "apps\\app1"
    },
    "app2": {
      "name": "app2",
      "integrations": {
        "capacitor": {}
      },
      "type": "vue",
      "root": "apps\\app2"
    },
    "app3": {
      "name": "app3",
      "integrations": {
        "capacitor": {}
      },
      "type": "vue",
      "root": "apps\\app3"
    }
  }
}
```

So far, when I open the first it goes to the default port (8100) and after that, each app goes to +1 (8101, 8102)

I was able to set the port through command line (--port=4000) but I havent been able to set it in a config file...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what your config script is (maybe we don't share the same framework) but if you want to define run port for vite just add `--port <port>` for example run `dev` on port `2345`:

```bash
vite dev --port 2345
```

Comment: Well, yes, you can redefine it in the command line, but I would like to be able to configure it in a config file... , as I said in the description... and I'm not using vite...